# Eclipse breakpoint events

Tags: eclipse, events, breakpoints

In my Eclipse plugin, I would like to be notified when a breakpoint is created, removed or disabled.

Is there an event that I can subscribe to for this?

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it, but from the docs it looks like you might be interested in IBreakpointManager.

It looks like you should add an IBreakpointListener or an IBreakpointsListener to this.

Have a look at this help section: http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/debug_breakpoints.htm